# Mongodb yaml `selector` does not match template `labels`

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, yaml

I'm trying to set up mongodb locally in a container using minikube, following this example repository here:
https://github.com/pkdone/minikube-mongodb-demo

I get the error:

```
The StatefulSet "mongod" is invalid:
* spec.selector: Required value
* spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"environment":"test", "replicaset":"MainRepSet", "role":"mongo"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`
```

Here is my full yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongod
spec:
  serviceName: mongodb-service
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        replicaset: MainRepSet
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: replicaset
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - MainRepSet
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-volume
          secret:
            secretName: shared-bootstrap-data
            defaultMode: 256
      containers:
        - name: mongod-container
          #image: pkdone/mongo-ent:3.4
          image: mongo
          command:
            - "numactl"
            - "--interleave=all"
            - "mongod"
            - "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB"
            - "0.1"
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "0.0.0.0"
            - "--replSet"
            - "MainRepSet"
            - "--auth"
            - "--clusterAuthMode"
            - "keyFile"
            - "--keyFile"
            - "/etc/secrets-volume/internal-auth-mongodb-keyfile"
            - "--setParameter"
            - "authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: 200Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-volume
              readOnly: true
              mountPath: /etc/secrets-volume
            - name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`spec.selector`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#statefulset-v1-apps) field is missing on your Statefulset template.

> selector is a label query over pods that should match the replica
>   count. **It must match the pod template's labels**. More info:
>   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors

You need to add the `spec.selector` to match one or more labels. Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongod
spec:
  serviceName: mongodb-service
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        replicaset: MainRepSet
...
```

---

The example that you are using is probably outdated. The [former `apps/v1beta1`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#statefulset-v1beta1-apps) added a default value for `spec.selector` if empty, which is not the case anymore.

> selector is a label query over pods that should match the replica
>   count. **If empty, defaulted to labels on the pod template**. More info:
>   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors

In `apps/v1beta2` and  `apps/v1` it should be explicitly set.